# MVC5 SignalR "500 timed out" in azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, signalr

I have an `ASP.NET MVC5` application which uses `SignalR`. Using a `BackgroundTimer : IRegisteredObject` I call some API's every 10 seconds that give me stock information (tickers from `Bitfinex`, `Kraken`, etc..) and sends them through SignalR to the clients where I show them using tables.

Locally my app works perfect. The problem occurs when I publish it to Azure. It starts to act really strange. It works until some point (sometimes a minute, sometimes a couple of hours) and at one moment when I want to access it I wait a couple of minutes until it gives me an `500 - The request timed out`. The way that I'm currently able to fix it is by starting to mess with the settings in the Azure Portal (turn on/off Diagnostic logs, etc) until at some point it starts working again. I tried to republish the code, sometimes it fixes it, sometimes it still gives me a timed out error.

When the app hangs I try to attach a debugger using the Cloud Explorer, but after staying at "Warming Up Site" for a minute or two, it gives me `Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger` When the site starts up again (which as I said happens in a very random interval ) I'm able to attach a debugger, but since the site is working during the debug session, I have no use from it.

I have not used azure in depth and I'm not sure where to search for an error log to investigate the issue. From VS Cloud Explorer -> Logs I found these interesting files:

1. /Detailed Errors:[When I try to debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt579.png),
2. /Application: [WebSocketException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lUeU.png)

   I'm sure the problem doesn't come from the HTTP API requests to the stock's sites because they have time limits and try catches. It's part of my app logic for them to sometimes be unreachable. My guess is a problem with SignalR (after looking at the WebSocketException), but I don't know what it could be. My setup is very basic (one hub, app.MapSignalR() without arguments) and in Azure I checked the "Enable WebSockets" option.

Here is some code:

`Startup.cs`

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

I tried to add `UseAesDataProtectorProvider()` before `app.MapSignalR();` as suggested [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3659#issuecomment-272924436) but it didn't change nothing.

`StatisticsHub.cs`

```
public class StatisticsHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        Clients.Caller.getLastTickers();
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public Task JoinGroup(string stockName)
    {
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, stockName);
    }

    public Task LeaveGroup(string stockName)
    {
        return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, stockName);
    }
}
```

}

JS connection to SignalR:

```
var statisticsHub = $.connection.statisticsHub;
statisticsHub.client.addNewTicker = function (ticker) {
    addTickerToTable(ticker);
};

statisticsHub.client.getLastTickers = function(tickers) {
    tickers.each(function(index, ticker) {
        addTickerToTable(ticker);
    });
}

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    assignEvents();
});
```

UPDATE:

This is the method I call every 20 seconds to get new tickers:

```
private void SendNewTickersToClients(object state)
{
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var ticker = BtcRates.GetTicker(StockName.BitFinexUsd);
            statisticsHub.Clients.Group(ticker.StockName).addNewTicker(ticker);
        });

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var ticker = BtcRates.GetTicker(StockName.BitFinexEur);
            statisticsHub.Clients.Group(ticker.StockName).addNewTicker(ticker);
        });

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var ticker = BtcRates.GetTicker(StockName.KrakenUsd);
            statisticsHub.Clients.Group(ticker.StockName).addNewTicker(ticker);
        });

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var ticker = BtcRates.GetTicker(StockName.KrakenEur);
            statisticsHub.Clients.Group(ticker.StockName).addNewTicker(ticker);
        });

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var ticker = BtcRates.GetTicker(StockName.GdaxUsd);
            statisticsHub.Clients.Group(ticker.StockName).addNewTicker(ticker);
        });

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var ticker = BtcRates.GetTicker(StockName.GdaxEur);
            statisticsHub.Clients.Group(ticker.StockName).addNewTicker(ticker);
        });

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var ticker = BtcRates.GetTicker(StockName.GeminiUsd);
            statisticsHub.Clients.Group(ticker.StockName).addNewTicker(ticker);
        });
}
```

In the Diagnose problems tab in azure I saw this statement: `Your app failed to make an outbound TCP connection because the machine-wide TCP Connection limit was hit`. Is it possible that these tasks open too many connections?

UPDATE 2:

I saw that the reason for the unsuccessful debug attaching is this error: `The controller for path '/DebugWarmUp' was not found or does not implement IController.`

UPDATE 3:

Upgraded to Basic tier and I haven't got any more problems. Turns out I was reaching some TCP outgoing connections limit.

Comment: Have you enabled "Always On" in the Azure Portal for your Web App? Just want to eliminate this one right out of the gate. Azure will unload inactive Web Apps and reload them to service requests as they come in.

Comment: I'm currently on a free tier which doesn't have this option. Non the less, I don't think this is it because it hangs as I'm refreshing and browsing the app (making requests to it). It doesn't happen only when no requests are coming in

Comment: Yes, there is an outbound connection limit from Web Apps. That connection limit increases as you scale up your instance.

Comment: Okay but I wonder how do I reach this limit..? Currently I make 7 requests every 20 seconds. After I receive the request isn't the outbound connection closed?

Comment: That is a good question, and I don't know. Try going to the Diagnose and Solve problems tab. Then click on Metrics Per Instance (Apps). Then expand TCPv4 and look at Connections Established. See if you see a sawtooth pattern where at a certain point things are going off the rails. Note that if you enable/disable certain logging features, it triggers an app recycle. Which would kill any open connections. This might explain what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Some troubleshooting tips for Web Apps:

1. First stop (as you've already mentioned) is the Diagnostics Logs tab. Turn on Application Logging, Web server logging, detailed error messages, and failed request tracing. You already know about checking the web server logs in Visual Studio.
2. Next, hit the Diagnose and Solve problems tab. I don't think you'll have luck here, but try the Failed Request Tracing. This will give you extremely detailed error logs for each failed request. You can see the output from the request pipeline here.
3. Next (still on Diagnose and Solve problems), check the Application Events. You may have more luck here if something is blowing up in the background that is not an explicit HTTP request to your server.
4. Next (still on Diagnose and Solve Problems), look at Metrics Per Instance and go through ALL options. I've found funny things (like runaway CPU, exhausted thread pools, etc) by looking at history for each metric over time. It's a good sanity check that can give you an idea if you see a metric way out of balance.
5. Instrument your code with Application Insights. There's a free version. It's super simple to do. In fact, Visual Studio will do it for you. This gives you very detailed info, including stack traces, for server exceptions. I instrument all my sites with Application Insights because it really aids in troubleshooting.